# Redux. Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to run a axios request in my react action, but it returns the error:

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
> actions.

My component

```
...
componentDidMount = async () => {
   await this.props.onLoadData();
   console.log(this.props.test);
}

...
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        events: state.dashboard.test
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onLoadData: async () => dispatch(action.loadData)
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

My action file

```
export const loadData = async () => {
    let data = [];
    await axios.get(`${api.URL}/events`)
        .then(res => {
            data = res.data
        });
    return {
        type: actionTypes.GET_TEST,
        payload: data
    };
}
```

My reducer:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionsTypes';

const initialState = {
    events: []
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.GET_TEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                events: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: As the error says, you need to set up middleware (looks like the thunk middleware specifically) in order to pass non-action values to `dispatch`. Redux docs have got you covered.

Comment: What @backtick said. See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#using-the-redux-thunk-middleware

Comment: Could you give an example in my code?

Comment: See [Redux Async Logic](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic).